My spring app is running successfully but I cant open my API in browser?
When I enter localhost:8080/api and try to access different http request I failed.
here is an example of my service class:
package services;

import models.Conducteur;
import models.Trip;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import repositories.ConducteurRepository;
import repositories.TripRepository;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ConducteurService {

    @Autowired
    private ConducteurRepository conducteurRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TripRepository tripRepository;

    // Méthode pour retourner la liste des conducteurs dispo dans une date spécéfique
    public List<Conducteur> findAvailableDrivers(LocalDate date) {
        List<Conducteur> allDrivers = (List<Conducteur>) conducteurRepository.findAll();

        List<Conducteur> availableDrivers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Conducteur conducteur : allDrivers) {
            if (isDriverAvailable(conducteur, date)) {
                availableDrivers.add(conducteur);
            }
        }
        return availableDrivers;
    }

    // Méthode pour vérifier la disponibilité d'un conducteur à une date spécifique
    private boolean isDriverAvailable(Conducteur conducteur, LocalDate date) {
        // Récupérer tous les voyages pour la date de départ spécifiée
        List<Trip> tripsForDate = tripRepository.findAllByDepartureDate(date);

        // Vérifier si le conducteur a des voyages pour cette date
        for (Trip trip : tripsForDate) {
            if (trip.getConducteur().equals(conducteur)) {
                return false; // Le conducteur a un voyage prévu pour cette date
            }
        }
        return true; // Le conducteur est disponible pour cette date
    }

    public long countConducteurs() {
        try {
            return conducteurRepository.count();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public void deleteConducteur(Conducteur conducteur) {
        try {
            conducteurRepository.delete(conducteur);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public void deleteAllConducteurs() {
        try {
            conducteurRepository.deleteAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public void deleteConducteursByMat(Iterable<String> mat) {
        try {
            conducteurRepository.deleteAllById(mat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public boolean existsConducteurByMat(String mat) {
        try {
            return conducteurRepository.existsById(mat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public List<Conducteur> findAllConducteurs() {
        try {
            return (List<Conducteur>) conducteurRepository.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public List<Conducteur> findAllConducteursByMat(Iterable<String> mats) {
        try {
            return (List<Conducteur>) conducteurRepository.findAllById(mats);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public Optional<Conducteur> findConducteurByMat(String mat) {
        try {
            return conducteurRepository.findById(mat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public Conducteur saveConducteur(Conducteur conducteur) {
        try {
            return conducteurRepository.save(conducteur);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }

    public List<Conducteur> saveAllConducteurs(Iterable<Conducteur> conducteurs) {
        try {
            return (List<Conducteur>) conducteurRepository.saveAll(conducteurs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e; // Re-lancer l'exception ou convertir en une exception personnalisée si nécessaire
        }
    }
}


and controllerClass:
package controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import services.ConducteurService;
import models.Conducteur;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/conducteurs")
public class ConducteurController {

    @Autowired
    private ConducteurService conducteurService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Conducteur>> getAllConducteurs() {
        List<Conducteur> conducteurs = conducteurService.findAllConducteurs();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(conducteurs);
    }
    @GetMapping("/{matricule}")
    public ResponseEntity<Conducteur> getConducteurByMatricule(@PathVariable String matricule) {
        Conducteur conducteur = conducteurService.findConducteurByMat(matricule)
                .orElse(null);

        if (conducteur != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(conducteur);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Conducteur> createConducteur(@RequestBody Conducteur conducteur) {
        try {
            Conducteur savedConducteur = conducteurService.saveConducteur(conducteur);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedConducteur);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/{matricule}")
    public ResponseEntity<Conducteur> updateConducteur(@PathVariable String matricule, @RequestBody Conducteur conducteurDetails) {
        Conducteur conducteur = conducteurService.findConducteurByMat(matricule)
                .orElse(null);

        if (conducteur != null) {
            // Update conducteur details
            conducteur.setNom(conducteurDetails.getNom());
            conducteur.setPrenom(conducteurDetails.getPrenom());
            conducteur.setDate_naissance(conducteurDetails.getDate_naissance());
            conducteur.setCIN(conducteurDetails.getCIN());
            conducteur.setTrips(conducteurDetails.getTrips());
            conducteur.setPermis(conducteurDetails.getPermis());

            // Save updated conducteur
            Conducteur updatedConducteur = conducteurService.saveConducteur(conducteur);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedConducteur);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{matricule}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteConducteur(@PathVariable String matricule) {
        Conducteur conducteur = conducteurService.findConducteurByMat(matricule)
                .orElse(null);

        if (conducteur != null) {
            conducteurService.deleteConducteur(conducteur);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}


I tried this :
http://localhost:8080/api/conducteurs/
I got this :
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri May 10 15:38:58 WEST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Your @RequestMapping is pointing on /api/conducteurs and not only /api.
So all your request are going to start with /api/conducteurs:

GET /api/conducteurs/
GET /api/conducteurs/{matricule}
POST /api/conducteurs/
DELETE /api/conducteurs/{matricule}

